# How to Crop an Image Precisely in the Shape of a Norman Window

Tags: graphics, xetex, pstricks, crop, shapes

A Norman Window looks like a semicircle atop a rectangle; for example,

[image]

If would like to be able to take an existing rectangular image and crop it so that what is cut out resembles the perimeter of a norman window.

Consider the code, which I compile with `Xelatex`---

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}


% Compiles with xelatex

\def\M{3}% columns
\def\N{3}% rows
\def\scale{1}% scale

\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[width=16em,height=20em]{example-image}}

\psset
{
  xunit=0.5\dimexpr\wd\IBox/\M\relax,
  yunit=0.5\dimexpr\ht\IBox/\N\relax,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-\M,-\N)(\M,\N)
    \rput(0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: How may I, if possible, precisely (not by "hand") crop this image in the shape of a *norman window* with the base of the rectangle beginning (from the left) at the point (x,y) = (-2,-1.5); and the dimensions of the said rectangle being x = 4 and y = 2.5?

Comment: Do we have to use pstricks?

Comment: @JohnKormylo It's not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses TikZ.  I assume the numbers were just for show.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Compiles with xelatex

\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[width=16em,height=20em]{example-image}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (0,0) -- (\wd\IBox,0) -- (\wd\IBox, \ht\IBox-0.5*\wd\IBox)
    arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius={0.5\wd\IBox}] -- cycle;
  \node[inner sep=0pt, above right] at (0,0) {\usebox\IBox};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The norman window is very nice. Perhaps you might consider posting a picture of the output so others can see how nice it is.

Comment: Thank you again,

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but it seems that the Norman Window is carved out of the entire rectangular image. Is there a way, perhaps, that one might customize the code a little, so that, say, only a portion of the picture's width, or only a portion of its height, may be specified to produce the Norman Window?

Comment: @jean-marie - The only limitation is that the width can't be greater than twice the height.  Simply select a smaller rectangle and possibly offset.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}% xelatex or lualatex
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=6cm]{example-image}}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=2}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](\wd\IBox,\ht\IBox)
\psclip{%
  \pscustom[linestyle=none,dimen=middle]{%
    \psline(\wd\IBox,0)(\wd\IBox,0.5\ht\IBox)
    \psarc(0.5\wd\IBox, 0.5\ht\IBox){0.5\wd\IBox}{0}{180}
    \psline(0,0)
  }}
\rput(0.5\wd\IBox,0.5\ht\IBox){\usebox\IBox}
\endpsclip
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]