# Colorizing a Norman Window Image Embedded in a Pspicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, color, pstricks, pspicture

This post is an extension of  [How to Crop an Image Precisely in the Shape of a Norman Window](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648115/how-to-crop-an-image-precisely-in-the-shape-of-a-norman-window/648118#648118)

Consider the code which embeds an image of a Norman Window inside a `pspicture`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz,pstricks,xcolor,graphicx}


% Compile with Xelatex

\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[width=12em,height=15em]{example-image}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,8)%
\psframe[fillcolor=red,fillstyle=solid](-4,-4)(4,8)
\rput(0,2.5){\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) -- (\wd\IBox,0) -- (\wd\IBox, \ht\IBox-0.5*\wd\IBox)
arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius={0.5\wd\IBox}] -- cycle;
\node[inner sep=0pt, above right] at (0,0) {\usebox\IBox};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

which produces the image

[image]

QUESTION: Compiling the code with `Xelatex`, how may I colorize the Norman Window, say, blue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
%\psset{unit=2}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-3,-3)(9,9)
\psframe*[linecolor=blue](-3,-3)(9,9)
\psclip{%
  \pscustom[linestyle=none,dimen=middle]{%
    \psline(6,0)(6,3)
    \psarc(3,3){3}{0}{180}
    \psline(0,0)
  }}
\psframe*[linecolor=red](-3,-3)(9,9)
\endpsclip
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of clipping you can use a simple `\pscustom`.

Answer (score 3):

Natural steps:

- Put the image on the bottom layer
- Put the window frame on the top

The most important concept is in the window frame. The transparent region is due to [even-odd rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule#:%7E:text=The%20SVG%20defines%20the%20even,shape%20that%20the%20ray%20crosses.).

The `pspicture*` removes the part of image outside the canvas.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newbox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid=t](-2,-2)(2,4)
\rput(0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\end{pspicture*}

\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid=t](-2,-2)(2,4)
\pscustom[dimen=m,linejoin=2,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]{%
    \psline(2,4)(2,-2)(-2,-2)(-2,4)\closepath% clockwise
    \psarc[liftpen=2](0,2){1}{0}{180}\psline(-1,2)(-1,-1)(1,-1)(1,2)\closepath% counter-clockwise
}
\end{pspicture*}

\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid=t](-2,-2)(2,4)
\rput(0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\pscustom[dimen=m,linejoin=2,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]{%
    \psline(2,4)(2,-2)(-2,-2)(-2,4)\closepath% clockwise
    \psarc[liftpen=2](0,2){1}{0}{180}\psline(-1,2)(-1,-1)(1,-1)(1,2)\closepath% counter-clockwise
}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

Note: The last `pspicture*` might be the output you want to use. The other ones are intentionally added just for creating the animation. So you need to remove the first two `pspicture*` and `showgrid=t` in your production.